# text field to label with CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a text field I want to show as a label.
This is the CSS I use:

```
.txtToLbl{
            color:Black;
            border: 0px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;

            /*text-align: center;*/
        }
```

You can still click the text field and change the values of the text field that has been changed to a label. Is there a way with CSS to disable this function?

(I can't update a label form the code behind therefore I use a text field)

Comment: Can you simplify your question?\

Comment: set the `readonly` attribute.`readonly="readonly"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No CSS but rather HTML attribute:

```
<input type="text" class="txtToLbl" readonly="readonly" />
```

If using ASP.NET control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" CssClass="txtToLbl" ReadOnly="true" />
```